# Triangle Probablity Distribution

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given the following probability distribution

[image]

Find $P(X<-0.75)+P(X>0.75)$.

I've found that
$$P(X<-0.75)+P(X>0.75)=2(\frac{(1-0.75)\cdot h}{2}),$$
where $h$ is the height of the shaded triangle.

How do we get the height?

Answer is $\frac{1}{16}$

**Edit 1:**

Since this is a probability distribution, the entire area $= 1$.

Area of entire triangle:
$\frac{(1-(-1))\cdot H}{2} = 1$

$H = 1$

We split the entire triangle in half vertically down the middle at $0$ so we get two triangles which have all 3 corner angles equal to its respective shaded triangles contained within. Now we use the property of similar triangles where the side-lengths of the shaded triangles are proportionate to its parent triangle.

$h = \frac{1-0.75}{1-0}\cdot H$

$h = \frac{1}{4}\cdot 1$

$h = \frac{1}{4}$

Thus,

$P(X<-0.75)+P(X>0.75)$

$=2(\frac{(1-0.75)\cdot \frac{1}{4}}{2})$

$=\frac{1}{16}$

Comment: Which height? $ $

Comment: @Did Of the shaded area, to get the area under the curve without knowing f(x).

Comment: Then we get the height h by computing the height above 0 and then using Thales.

Comment: @Did That is a rather obscure comment...

Comment: @Servaes Really? Any notion escaping you in it? Please be specific.

Comment: @Did *"...by computing the height above $0$..."* of what? On a second reading, I guess you mean the height of the graph at $x=0$, I first read it as the height above the line $y=0$. Not sure how Thales comes in though, but by means of similar triangles it is immediate what $h$ is.

Comment: @Servaes IOW a second reading allowed you to fully understand this comment. Congrats.

Comment: @Did Actually I still have no idea how you intend to use Thales, as a second reading of my comment might show ;) It would also show that your earlier comment is rather ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A probability distribution integrates to $1$, i.e. the area of the big triangle must be $1$. What must its height then be? Now use similar triangles to compute the height of the smaller triangles.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. See **Edit 1**

Answer (score 1):

Note that from $-1$ to $0$ you capture $0.5$ of the total probability, then use facts about similar triangles to find the height ($h$) you require.

More specifically, you know that $Pr(-1<X<0) = 0.5$. Hopefully from here on in you can use the expression for the area of a triangle to calculate the height of the triangle as a whole.

Next, use the similar triangle ratio expression to find your required height.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to find the height. If you join the two shaded small triangles, you will get a triangle similar to large one. Using the property of similar triangles:
$$\frac{S_1}{S}=\left(\frac{a_1}{a}\right)^2 \Rightarrow \frac{S_1}{1}=\left(\frac{0.5}{2}\right)^2 \Rightarrow S_1=\frac{1}{16}.$$

Comment: Interesting, I think this is how they did it in the book. Could you elaborate on what the variables stand for?  Thanks!

Comment: $S$ and $S_1$ are the areas of large and small (formed by joining the two shaded triangles) triangles. Hence $a$ and $a_1$ are the bases of the large and small triangles, respectively.